# What is kernel mode software?

Tags: windows, driver, digital-signature, kernel-mode

I'm looking into signing a driver I made.  A lot of the Microsoft documentation references "kernel mode software."  What is that?  It's mentioned in a lot of places, but it doesn't seem to be defined anywhere.  How do I know if my driver is kernel mode software?  My driver is a customized version of the Silicon Labs VCP driver.  Thanks.

Comment: How do you write a driver without knowing about kernel mode and user mode?

Comment: virtual comm port drivers are kernel mode

Comment: @David: I don't think he wrote it, he said he "customized" another driver, which probably just means changing VID/PID in the .inf file.

Comment: @David Hefferman: Silicon Labs provides a wizard to customize their driver with your own branding, etc.  All you have to do is go through it and select the options you want; no code writing is necessary.

Comment: @Ben I see now. It seems that Ben has your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a good general link on this: [Windows Programming/User Mode vs Kernel Mode](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Windows_Programming/User_Mode_vs_Kernel_Mode)